# Selenium Can't Click Specific Checkbox

Tags: java, html, selenium, xpath, checkbox

Hi guys okay so I am a relative (read: complete) newbie to Selenium / Java / HTML so apologies if I am asking the obvious. 
What I need is to be able to

1. Click on Specific Checkbox 1 and
2. If Specific Checkbox 2 is checked, to uncheck it

Here is the Website HTML:

Specific Checkbox 1

```
<div class="checkbox">
    <label id="agree_to_terms_label" for="agree_to_terms_join" class="visible">
      <input id="agree_to_terms_join" name="agree_to_terms" type="checkbox" data-required="true" data-required-message="You need to agree to the *** Account Holder agreement" data-change="" class="parsley-validated">
      <span class="left-block"></span>
      I have read, understand and agree to the <a href="/terms-and-conditions/" target="_blank">*** Account Holder Agreement</a>
      and acknowledge <a href="/privacy-policy" target="_blank">*** Privacy Policy</a>
      <input type="hidden" name="agree_to_terms" value="yes">
    </label>
  </div>
```

Specific Checkbox 2:

```
<div class="checkbox">
    <label id="agree_to_offers_label" for="agree_to_offers" class="visible">
      <span class="left-block">
         <input id="agree_to_offers" name="agree_to_offers" type="checkbox" data-required-message="" data-change="" checked="checked" value="yes">
        <span>By joining *** you'll be notified of exclusive offers and account updates via email</span>
      </span>
    </label>
  </div>
```

My fruitless attempts:

Xpath:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@id='agree_to_terms_join' and @type='checkbox']")).click();
```

Element not visible

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='agree_to_terms_join']/parent::label")).click();
```

Clicks on the href hyperlinks within the div instead

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='agree_to_terms_label']/input")).click();
```

Element not visible

CSS:

```
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("input[id = 'agree_to_terms_join'][type = 'checkbox']")).click();
```

Element not visible

by.className:

```
driver.findElement(By.className("checkbox")).click();
```

Opens hyperlinks

I had a look around the forums and saw mention of elements being hidden away - however I can't spot any iframes or anything else that appears to be hiding the bugger?

Any help would be greatly appreciated!!

Comment: Please check whether is frame

Comment: Hi I checked for a frame but it doesn't look like there is one. It seems like it isn't visible for another reason (which I don't know yet)

Comment: Can u share URL

Comment: Try using id dear

Comment: Yes here: https://www.quidco.com/join-quidco/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try following:

```
WebElement yourChkBox  = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='agree_to_terms_join']/parent::label"));

WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 20);
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOf(yourChkBox));

Actions act = new Actions(driver);
act.moveToElement(yourChkBox).click().build().perform();
```

**UPDATE:**

OR try using javascriptexecutor as below:

```
WebElement yourChkBox  = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='agree_to_terms_join']/parent::label"));

JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;        
js.executeScript("arguments[0].setAttribute('value', 'Yes');", yourChkBox  );
```

Comment: Thanks just tried this:

@And ("^Checks relevant boxes$")
 public void checksBoxes() {
  
  //driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//label[@id='agree_to_terms_label']")).click();
  
  WebElement yourChkBox = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='agree_to_terms_join']/parent::label"));

  WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 60); wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOf(yourChkBox));

  Actions act = new Actions(driver); act.moveToElement(yourChkBox).click().build().perform();
  
 }

Comment: But I still can't get it to click on the checkbox - the hyperlink keeps opening instead. Not sure what I am doing wrong!

Comment: I used this with your code instead:

js.executeScript("arguments[0].click();", yourChkBox  );

and it worked! Many thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

Your exact element to click on is "::before" which is a pseudo element. I think you would need to use Javascript. Below code should work for you

```
WebElement element1 = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(".left-block"));
JavascriptExecutor executor = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
executor.executeScript("arguments[0].click();", element1);
```

Comment: You are an absolute star - this works! However there are two .left-block classes in the web html - would you know how I can ask Selenium to specify which one I want? So for instance I want Specific Checkbox 1 (in my original question) to be selected *only*, but not Checkbox 2 (if that makes sense?)

Comment: Thanks man. You can always specify the index. Something like `WebElement element1 = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(".left-block")[Index]);` where index will start from 1

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
WebDriver driver=new FirefoxDriver();
driver.manage().window().maximize();
driver.get("https://www.quidco.com/join-quidco/");          
driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//label[@id='agree_to_terms_label']")).click();         
driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//label[@id='agree_to_offers_label']")).click();
```

If necessary put implicit or explicit wait

Comment: wait i will try

Comment: Tried it but it opens up the hyperlinks in that div class instead whereas I am trying to select the checkbox only...I also tried making the webdriver wait and it still does not locate element. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: You can click on label to select it. Please show ur code. Because it is workin in MY PC. Also it doesnt open hyper link. I copied the code use it

Comment: if possible copy your code in questions. This code is quite simple

Comment: @And ("^Checks relevant boxes$")
 public void checksBoxes() {
  
  driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//label[@id='agree_to_terms_label']")).click();
  
 }

Comment: I thought I copied my codes in the original question? Apologies if I misunderstood - I'm still new to all this.

Comment: No issue. u Make function. use it simple jusr copy paste this code in another program and run it. If it is running it means ur code have some issue

Comment: Same thing i told to u dear...use wait nywy :)